# Laravel 5.3 keep going to /home view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Kindly help me to solve this Auth redirect issue.

Currently i'm using laravel 5.3.22. I already put

```
protected $redirectTo = 'dashboard';
```

into my loginController.

Then i test redirect in my browser:

```
http://myapp.localhost/login
```

it shows "Login Page" correctly. Then i continue to login, it redirect me to "Dashboard" correctly.

The issue is here. After i successfully login, if i tried to go to

```
http://myapp.localhost/login
```

it redirect me to "Home" which is not available. It should be go to "Dashboard".

Please help me.

Comment: Did you edit the middleware ? cause by default 'RedirectIfAuthenticated.php' this middleware will redirect user to home page when user try to attempt login page when user are logged in

Comment: Yep, the middleware is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look in the `folder /app/http/Middleware/` there you should see the following file `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

Change it from:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
```

To :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
```

You should be fine.

Note, that the

> `/app/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

directs where you are sent after login, while

> `/app/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

controls where user is sent if `domain.app/login` request is requested after successfully loging in.

Comment: Yes this is where the issue come from. Thank you for your helpful help. I've test the code, now it's redirect me correctly to `http://myapp.localhost/dashboard` if user already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you need add to routes.php the route 
At first create 
1- Controller with Artisan php make::HomeController
2- Add route in app dir Route::get('/home', function () { return view('home'); });
3- later you need create a page called home.blade.php in your dir resources/views/home.blade.php

Comment: After the intsllation of Laravel check if in your database are present the table users and session if dont appears - you need do command php artisan migrate to create tables! or php artisan make_auth

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i need the redirect goes to "Dashboard" not "Home". After successfully login process, it correctly redirect to Dashboard. But if i already login, then i manually go to `http://myapp.localhost/login` it redirect me to `http://myapp.localhost/home` instead of `http://myapp.localhost/dashboard`

Comment: Route::get('/dasboard', function () { return view('dashborad'); });

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { Route::get('/dasboard', function () { return view('dashborad'); }); });

Comment: the last route if you are loggedin redirect to dashboard (Y)

Answer (score 0):

That's wierd...
Have you ever cleared the cache?

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php artisan config:clear
$ php artisan clear-compiled
```

if you was not succeed performing the above steps jump to the following approach: **LoginController** uses `AuthenticatesUsers` trait which uses `RedirectsUsers` trait which owns `redirectPath()` method. In this case you can override it like this:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    return '/Dashboard';
}
```

As you've might figured out  it, you must put the snippet in the LoginController.